# HtmlTags within Resx displayed in @Html.ValidationMessageFor

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, razor, resources, mvchtmlstring

I have the following doubt. I am considering the option to have html tags within my resx texts for localization. 
When I put the resources directly I can resort to:

```
@Html.Raw(@Resources.ResourcesFM.Error_Email)
```

and it works as expected.
The problem is when the resource is being called by a validation message from an htmlhelper:

```
@Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Email)
```

Got from an attibute:

```
[DataType(DataType.EmailAddress,
ErrorMessageResourceType = typeof(ResourcesFM),
ErrorMessageResourceName = "ErrorMailIncorr")]
```

What I am trying...

```
@Html.Raw(Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Email))
```

I do not know how to get the same result as when using @html.Raw as the output from the helper is a MvcHtmlString...

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

View:

```
@Html.Raw(Server.HtmlDecode(@Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.UserName).ToString()))
```

Controller Action:

```
ModelState.AddModelError("UserName", "This is a link <a href='http://example.com'>Google Home</a>");
```

Comment: If you indent your text by 4 spaces or 1 tab, it is interpreted as code (adding highlighting, allowing `<a>` tags ...).

Answer (score 0):

`Html.ValidationMessageFor` html-encodes the message. But you should be able to simply call `HttpUtility.HtmlDecode()` on the result. Even though the result contains html tags and whatnot, the decode will simply no-op on that part of the string.

So if `Html.ValidationMessageFor(...)' returns

```
<span>&lt;div&gt;This is in a div&lt;/div<&gt;</span>
```

Then `HttpUtility.HtmlDecode(Html.ValidationMessageFor(...).ToString())` will give you

```
<span><div>This is in a div</div></span>
```

It's not pretty, but it works. Your alternative is to recreate your own Validation helper version that never encodes the message.

Comment: Hi Bhamlin:'The best overloaded match for "System.Web.HttpUtility.HtmlDecode(String)' has some invalid arguments --> This is what i get when i put :HttpUtility.HtmlDecode(Html.ValidationMessageFor(...))...

Comment: It takes a string, not an HtmlString. Just call ToString() on it. I've updated my answer.

Comment: Thanks Bhamlin when doing HttpUtility.HtmlDecode(Html.ValidationMessageFor(...).ToString()): HTML code appears in my page without having any error: <span class="field-validation-valid" data-valmsg-for="Email" data-valmsg-replace="true"></span>

Comment: Sorry bhamlin I have not expressed myself correctly . What I meant is that without having any error in the field of the form (there is no validation message being rendered), this html:<span class="field-validation-valid" data-valmsg-for="Email" data-valmsg-replace="true"></span> is being rendered in the page. I am still unable to display the resources with html tags if they are a validation error...

Comment: Hah, thought you mean no error as in no problems. Anyway that's normal, it doesn't actually set the message in the span unless there's an error. There should be a some `data-val` attribute on the actual field that has the the error, and jquery validate will inject it into the span if there's an error.

Comment: Hi Bahmlin, and I do not get how can I make jquery insert properly the error messages with the html tags eg:<span style="..."> that are in my resource files

Comment: mcartur, the resource is output on the input element. I recommend reading http://bradwilson.typepad.com/blog/2010/10/mvc3-unobtrusive-validation.html which should explain how MVC interacts with jquery validation.

Comment: Hi Bahmlin I think that the only way is to change the validation helper as you pointed (I will check also how can I deal with Jquery to insert the error message adding the html tags that are encoded)

Answer (score 0):

For Localization, you may use String.Format and choose appropriate placeholder for the link

```
ModelState.AddModelError("UserName", String.Format("This is a link {0}", "<a href='http://example.com'>Appropriate String From a Resource</a>"));
```

Comment: I think this is the solution I will be using. Thanks¡¡